# passing result of method as global value

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here? I am attempting to avoid having to type and re-declare all the variables for an account inside the method.

```
#https://github.com/nukeproof/oanda_api
require 'oanda_api'
#require 'rsruby'
require 'indicators'

def createOrder(instrument="EUR_USD",type="market",units)
    order = $client.$account($acct_id).order(instrument: "EUR_USD",type: "market",side: type,units: units).create
    puts "time: "+order.time+"\nprice: "+order.price+"\nid: "+order.trade_opened.id
    return(order.trade_opened.id)
end

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE #bad practice...anyone who copies this code dont do this!
$acct_id=123456
$acct_token="abcd"

$client = OandaAPI::Client::TokenClient.new(:practice, $acct_token)
$account = client.account($acct_id).get

createOrder(units:1000)
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\king\Desktop\_REPOS\misc\stock_analysis\forex\oanda\ruby>ruby basicnukeproof.rb
basicnukeproof.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tGVAR, expecting '('
        order = $client.$account($acct_id).order(instrument: ...
```

Comment: Why the downvote to this post? How can I improve it if you see a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code is invalid

```
$client.$account(...)
```

If you write `$client.`, then the next thing that Ruby expects to see is the name of a method, and method names cannot begin with `$` so `$account` is invalid.  Try removing the dollar sign from `$account` there.

Comment: That worked, but I would love to find a method that didnt involve recalculating the account value every time. Any ideas?